# Type mismatch while sorting a list in xtend

Tags: type-mismatch, xtend

I try to sort a list using xtend. Here is the code:

```
def String traverse (EObject obj) {
    var String output = switch (obj) {
        TextInput: "["+obj.eClass.name+ "] " + obj.fullyQualifiedName + " (label: "+obj.labelText+")\n"
        OptionInput: "["+obj.eClass.name+ "] " + obj.fullyQualifiedName + " (label: "+obj.labelText+")\n"
        ContainerElement: "["+obj.eClass.name+ "] " + obj.fullyQualifiedName + "\n"
        ContentElement: "["+obj.eClass.name+ "] " + obj.name + "\n"
        default: ""
    }

    val objs = obj.eContents.sort([EObject obj1, EObject obj2 |
            if (obj1 instanceof ContainerElement && obj2 instanceof ContentElement) return 1
            else if (obj2 instanceof ContainerElement && obj1 instanceof ContentElement) return -1
            else return 0
        ])

    for (child : objs) {
        output = output + traverse(child);
    }
    output
}
```

EObjects contain an attribute eContents which is of type EList. The EList interface extends the java interface List.

For the sort statement I get the error: "Type mismatch: type void is not applicable at this location".

Any ideas what could be the problem here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

sort(..) is a default method of java.util.List that returns void. You may want to use sortBy(..) instead.

Comment: Thank you. You gave me the hint in the right direction ;) 

Actually the sort method from the xtext extension library was meant. But it is deprecated now, so using sortWith is the solution here. 

I just see that I don't tell you anything new as you are the author of the IterableExtension class ;)